# JNI dll file executes fine outside the tomcat. but doesnot run in tomcat ,even after i put the dll file in tomcat/bin without using ide like eclipse

Tags: tomcat, dll, java-native-interface, noclassdeffounderror

This is my class which is invoke from a servlet in my web application.

```
public class Cpro
{
    public native int id();
    public int unique()
    {
        int a=new Cpro().id();
        return a;
    }
    static{

        System.load("Cpro.dll");

     }
}
```

Comment: this works when i use normally without using tomcat.but i can't get answer while using tomcat it shows error class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Cpro
 AddStudent.doPost(AddStudent.java:41)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your native library in application resources. At application start you can store it to temp directory (for example) and load it by absolute file path according `System.load()` javadoc:

> Loads the native library specified by the filename argument. The filename argument must be an absolute path name.

For example:

```
InputStream dllResourceStream = null;
try {
    ClassLoader cl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
    // obtain dll resource stream
    dllResourceStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("path/to/dll/resource");
    File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("my_dll_name", ".dll");
    // store dll to temp dirictory
    Files.copy(dllResourceStream, tmpFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    // load dll via absolute file path
    System.load(tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());
} catch(AccessDeniedException e) {
    throw new IOException("Unable to install twain libraries", e);
} finally {
    if(dllResourceStream != null) resourceStream.close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply@sergey. but i solved my problem ,the problem is due mismatch in jvm 32 bit and dll 64 file bit